# SLF4J log same class at different levels in different appenders

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have two appenders, in this case a console appender and a rolling file appender.
For a certain class' log output (in this case `com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport`), how do I get this class to log at `DEBUG` level in one appender and `WARN` level at the other appender?

This doesn't seem to be a very complicated thing to ask, but unfortunately it seems totally outside the typical use cases I can find examples for.  I'm not trying to avoid coding my own Filter, but I'd be surprised if that's really the answer here.

I'm using Spring Boot and I do prefer to use JavaConfig, if that matters.

Thanks everyone for your responses! I am extremely happy to learn more by reading opinions on the 'right' way to do this, please check if you've first answered the original question before moving on :)

Comment: Could you update your question to state which logging implementaiton you are using? Logback? Log4j? java.util.logging?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Logback's `ThresholdFilter` to filter the events received by an appender and you can associate these filtered appenders with loggers for this class: `com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport`.

Your question states:

> I'm using Spring Boot and I do prefer to use JavaConfig, if that matters.

So, I'm assuming you are creating appenders programmatically. You can create a `ThresholdFilter` and associated it with an appender like so:

```
ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
ThresholdFilter debugFilter = new ThresholdFilter();
debugFilter.setLevel("DEBUG");
consoleAppender.addFilter(debugFilter);
...

FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new FileAppender<>();
ThresholdFilter warnFilter = new ThresholdFilter();
warnFilter.setLevel("WARN");
fileAppender.addFilter(warnFilter);
...
```

You would then need to associate these appenders with the specific logger like so:

```
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport");
logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
logger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
```

Here's the same approach using XML config:

```
<appender name="DEBUG_STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- only accept DEBUG log events -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>...</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="WARN_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!-- only accept WARN log events -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>...</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>...</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- associate this logger instance with the two appenders -->
<logger name="com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport">
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="WARN_FILE"/>
</logger>
```